# How to read different file format data and use it for compression

Tags: file-io, python-2.7

```
fob = open('this.txt','rb')
fob1 = open('that.txt','wb')
content = ''
for i in fob:
    content += i
fob1.write(content)
fob.close()
fob1.close()
```

This is a code that is used to read a txt file and store it in a txt file.. How do I read any kind of file??? tht might evn be a jpeg file,pdf file or someother file.. Pls do help me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you want to read the file byte by byte to manipulate the its content? (in that case, each different extension has different rules for the meaning of its bits) Or, do you want to just display the file's content?

Answer (score 1):

Your code reads a *.txt file line by line (and copies it).

If you want to read a different type of file byte by byte, and print its bits you can do this:

```
f = open('test.gnu','rb')
flag=1;
while flag:
    byte = f.read(1)
    flag = (byte != "")
    if flag:
        # do something with the byte, eg:
        # print its bits:
        print '{0:08b}'.format(ord(byte))
f.close()
```

Or if you want to zip and unzip files, you can use the package "zipfile"
http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile; for code with examples with various compression formats see:
http://pymotw.com/2/compression.html